# How to send 0x80 byte to a tcp port using netcat or similar tool?

Tags: tcp, netcat, binary

I'm trying to make a Memcached server respond as if I were using a binary protocol. If possible just command line answers pls, no code snippet in any programming language.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use:

```
echo -e '\x80' | nc host port
```

Comment: I needed to send two bytes; this worked for me: 
`echo -e '\x04''\x03' | nc host port`

Comment: You do not need to quote every escape sequence, just leave it between the same single quotes.